# How can I make creating arrays of objects more efficient?

Tags: php, sql, oop, class

I'm trying to shave valuable tenths of a second from my page generation time (it's up to 0.9 seconds!) and I wondered if there's a more efficient way of loading the following (example) data.

Imagine you have a class that describes a user, and a class that describes an post written by a user.

To list various properties of each post written by a particular user, you might use the following code:

```
$user = new User( $user_id );
$post_array = $user->get_posts();
```

Inside the User class would be the following code:

```
function get_posts()
{
    $posts_array = array();
    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE author = '" . $this->id . "'" );
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
    {
        $posts_array[] = new Post( $row['id'] );
    }
}
```

I don't like the fact that I have to hit the database twice, once to get the post IDs and again each time I instantiate the Post class. Have I coded myself into a corner? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Would it be bad practice to pass all the post's data to the instantiated Post object using `SELECT * FROM posts...` and then use `$posts_array[] = new Post( $row );`?

Comment: How about a PostTable class that will have a method which fetches posts by user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem doing the big query once (i.e. `SELECT *`) and then passing it to the post object, perhaps by a special method or static constructor (e.g., `Post::createPostFromData()`).  In fact, I believe this is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and it comes highly recommended, as design patterns go.

#### EDIT: In Re - `DRY`

Unless I'm completely mistaken, the `DRY` principle refers specifically to code, i.e. don't have several segments of code which do the same thing, or are literally the same lines of code with 0 or more tiny variations, and if you do, break them into functions/methods/what-have-you.  The reasons are legion, but focus largely on maintenance and debugging -- if anything needs changing, then with `DRY` you need only change it once.

In this case there is no reason to repeat code, or even queries, since you are simply populating the object using pre-built data.  However, if you wanted to add code that allowed you to fetch a post by ID and then populated the object, then it would become entirely possible to violate DRY by writing the code to populate the object twice, even if the data is from multiple sources.

In such a case, I would advocate using purely static constructors so that you can completely control the conditions of instantiation, for example:

```
class Post {
    // object properties
    protected $post_id;
    public $post_name;
    // ...

    protected function __construct($post_id, $post_data = null) {
        if (is_null($post_data)) {
            // create $post_data object by fetching $post_id
        }
        // code to populate the object
    }

    public static function fromData($data) {
        if (!is_array($data)) {
            return false;
        }
        return new self(null, $data);
    }

    public static function fromId($post_id) {
        if (!ctype_digit((string)$post_id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return new self($post_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this violate the DRY principle, by requiring the same SQL query every time I want to instantiate the class?

Comment: my response got too long, so I just edited the answer, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this. I would upvote again if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the not-so-wonderful world of object-relational mapping!

In terms of "OO design purity," the way you're doing it now has the advantages of straightforward implementation and on-demand loading of pertinent chunks of data from the DB as it's needed. A MySQL query takes time, but so does transferring large result sets over the wire. Beware premature optimization and be aware of other strategies you can implement to reduce your page load times that might be more effective and easier to implement. Are you sure this aspect of your application is having a substantial impact on load time? Even if it is, have you looked into a PHP bytecode cache or the MySQL query cache?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will look into PHP caching. In fact, the database is running on MS SQL Server, but I didn't want to muddy the waters. In any case, I have no control over software running on the SQL Server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a query each time you want to fetch a Post, why not have a PostSet that returns Posts using a single query?  You could make it lazy so that it only runs the query when you start getting Posts from it.  For convenience, take a look at the Zend Framework, particularly Zend_Db and Zend_Db_Table.  You don't have to use the whole framework--only the classes that you need.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html

Answer (score 0):

What about using an INNER JOIN Query?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_table.id, post_table.id, post_table.user_id FROM user_table INNER JOIN post_table ON post_table.user_id = user_table.id WHERE user_table.name = '".$user_name);
```

**Note: I have not tested the "WHERE" part of this, but I have used JOIN before. This is more of a theory than an answer.

The user selection can be built on whatever column you want it to be.

INNER JOIN Example:
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp